# CFCATCH throwing error in CFC

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

For some reason, a piece of code that works fine on a `*.cfm` page, and did work fine in a `*.cfc`, now is throwing an error when error is detected.

The error is:

```
Element SQL is undefined in CFCATCH.
```

The code block where this is getting throw looks like this:

```
<cfcatch type="database">
    <cfset errorMessage = "
        <p>#cfcatch.message#</p>
        <p>Please send the following to a developer:</p>
        <p>#cfcatch.SQL#</p> <--- ERROR HERE
        <p>#cfcatch.queryError#</p>
        <p>#cfcatch.Where#</p>">
    some other stuff
</cfcatch>
```

Any thoughts?

***UPDATE***

Using @BenKoshy suggestion, I modified my `<cfcatch>` statement.

Remember K.I.S.S.? Keep It Simple Stupid

Using his method and then modifying it, I was getting more data back than I was going use, so I went with a simple version, and it works as advertised.

```
<cfif isDefined("cfcatch.message")>
  <cfset errorMessage = errorMessage & "<p>#cfcatch.message#</p>">
</cfif>
<cfif isDefined("cfcatch.SQL")>
    <cfset errorMessage = errorMessage & "<p>Please send the following to a developer:</p><p>#cfcatch.SQL#</p>">
</cfif>
<cfif isDefined("cfcatch.QueryError")>
    <cfset errorMessage = errorMessage & "<p>#cfcatch.queryError#</p>">
</cfif>
<cfif isDefined("cfcatch.Where")>
    <cfset errorMessage = errorMessage & "<p>#cfcatch.Where#</p>">
</cfif>
```

Nice and easy and it works. KISS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just means the error data did not contain an SQL statement.  Shouldn't assume that variable will exist for all errors:

```
<cfif isDefined("cfcatch.sql")>
     <p>#cfcatch.SQL#</p>
 </cfif>
```

Is the easy fix.  Probably best to loop through the struct like this:

```
<cfparam name="errorMessage" default="">
<cfloop collection="#cfcatch#" item="this">
    <cfset errorMessage = errorMessage & "<p>#cfcatch[this]#</p>">
</cfloop>
```

Comment: `structKeyExists(cfcatch,"sql")` is more precise. I'd use that over `isDefined()`.

Comment: The last item in the collection is an array `cfcatch.tagContext` is the item.  This will throw a "complex object ... simple value.  So the above example doesn't work as written, but thanks for the tip. The issue was with data, and that is probably the reason it was throwing the error in the first place, but I would have figured that even thought it was a data issue `Invalid data asdf for CFSQLTYPE CF_SQL_FLOAT.` cfcatch would have sorted it out.